# How to send Image to server with out downloading it to memory?

Tags: android, image-processing, multipart, multipartentity

I'm getting Facebook profile image url, what I'm doing is downloading that image to the memory using

```
String extension = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("."));
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/" + extension);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);
    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

and I'm uploading it to the server using Multiparty entity:

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strProfilePic)) {
            File file = new File(strProfilePic);
            if (file.exists()) {
                FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
                entity.addPart("profile_picture", fileBody);
            }
        }
```

The problem here is, accessing the Image in gallery I have to set permission which is annoying as user is not actually trying to upload the image so if he deny then image wont be uploaded.

Is there any way I can send an Image to server with out downloading it to the memory

Comment: delete the image after image gets uploaded

Comment: I don't want to download! first of all, why download and delete, I want to send directly

Comment: Send the URL and have the server fetch the image.  If you can't do that then you're going to have to download the image on the phone.